# Django ORM to sum two columns to fill a third one

Tags: python, django, sqlite, sorting, django-tables2

Lets say, I have a SQLite table like this:

```
A  |  B | SUM
-------------
AA | BA |
AB | BB |
AC | BC |
```

and now I'd like to set numeric values to them, to fill in a third column.
For example:

```
AA = 1  BA = 1
AB = 3  BB = 3
AC = 2  BC = 2
```

So the table in database would be like this:

```
A  |  B | SUM
-------------
AA | BA | 2
AB | BB | 6
AC | BC | 4
```

I'm doing this because, I added a django-tables2 table to my project and I'd like to custom sort my table, but as far as I searched, there is no way to do this. I can only sort table by column A or B. But it orders them in alphabetical order and my values are different.

The other possibility would be to use SQL query to sort my table like this:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN A = 'AA' THEN 1
              WHEN A = 'AB' THEN 3
              WHEN A = 'AC' THEN 2 END
```

But I'd have to use raw method in django to do this, right? Inserting it with ORM is not possible? At least that's what I've understood this far. Or I just dont know how to do this. :P

So instead of using raw, I thought it would be simple to add a third column just to order the whole table by that ;)

Well, it turned out not to be as simple as I hoped and I would like to get any help if possible. 
Thank you!

Comment: What is your question? You can calculate the value in the third column in the model's save() method.

Comment: I'm a real noob, so could you please give me an example. I should write the code into models.py file? fe. I have a class Example(models.Model), with 3 columns: A, B and SUM. How to specify that I want AA to equal 2 and AB equal 3 etc?

Comment: I've posted a suggestion. It would be easier to answer if you had included your model code in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do it. Naming the modelfields `field_a` or `field_sum` isn't recommended, but better than just `a` or `sum`.

```
from django.db import models


class Example(models.Model):
    VALUES = {
        'AA': 1,
        'AB': 3,
        'AC': 2,
        'BA': 1,
        'BB': 3,
        'BC': 2,
    }

    field_a = models.CharField(default='AA', max_length=2,)
    field_b = models.CharField(default='BA', max_length=2,)

    # The value in this field is derived from the first two.
    # Updated every time the model instance is saved.
    field_sum = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0,  # This value will be overwritten during save()
        editable=False,  # Hides this field in the admin interface.
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # calculate sum before saving.
        self.field_sum = self.calculate_sum()
        super(Example, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def calculate_sum(self):
        """ Calculate a numeric value for the model instance. """
        try:
            value_a = self.VALUES[self.field_a]
            value_b = self.VALUES[self.field_b]
            return value_a + value_b
        except KeyError:
            # Value_a or value_b is not in the VALUES dictionary.
            # Do something to handle this exception.
            # Just returning the value 0 will avoid crashes, but could 
            # also hide some underlying problem with your data.
            return 0
```

The Django documentation about overriding the save() method:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods

You might want to read a bit about database design and normalization. It's often not a good idea to store derived values in the database.

If you change the VALUES dictionary or update the table without using the Django ORM and the save() method, the value in field_sum might be wrong.

Saving all instances will make sure that the field_sum is correct.

```
for instance in Example.objects.all(): instance.save()
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! This is what I meant! Sorry for not providing a model example, but good improvising by you! P.S - a little typo in def save. Should be self.calculate_sum(). ;)

Comment: I changed the example code a bit. I have not tested it, so there might still be some typos.