# How to filter in Django DB based on calculations from different tables

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have **3 models** from **3 different tables**:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    player_surname=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        db_table='profiles'

class Results_2019(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=150) 
    first_score=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)
    second_score=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)

    class Meta:
        db_table='results_2019'


class Results_2018(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)         
    first_score=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)
    second_score=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)

    class Meta:
        db_table='results_2018'
```

The database is static. Player in all three models have the same names =['Alex','Chandler','Zach'] and they all have data belonging to them for all columns ( `first_score,second_score`)

**Profile database** look like :

```
id player_name    player_surname    

1   Alex           Chapman          
2   Chandler       Wellington           
3   Zach           Berg
```

**Results_2019 database** look like :

```
id  profile_id  player_name   first_score   second_score

1      1           Alex         70            68
2      2           Chandler     60            62
3      3           Zach         90            85
```

**Results_2018 database** look like :

```
id  profile_id  player_name     first_score     second_score

1     1              Alex             78                81
2     2              Chandler         56                66
3     3              Zach             97                95
```

I want to make calculations based on values from Results_2019 and Results_2018  to get:

**- players whos growth in first_score and second_score in 2019 and in 2018 were more than 20% and then get the name and surnames who met these criteria and print in template.**

The below formula of criteria  though does not work i show as guidance of what i want to achieve.

```
first_score_growth=((Results_2019.first_score/Results_2018.first_score)*100)
```

**and**

```
second_score_growth=((Results_2019.second_score/Results_2018.second_score)*100)
```

What i could do so far :

For this purpose i assigned Foreign key thorugn DB i have seperate column in mysql `prodile_id`. However it does not do even migrations.

What i could calculate and filter results from  **1 DB** table (`Results_2019`):

```
total=Results_2019.objects.annotate(
total_score=(F('first_score') + F('second_score'))/2).filter(total_score__gt=80,)
```

But this calculates total score for year 2019 but not the growth.

Also  when i add foreign key to Results_2019 it gives me such **OperationalError**   (1054, "Unknown column 'Results_2019.profile_id' in 'field list'")

I would appreciate your help to sort this out.

Comment: you can use the foreign key with profile model, then annotate on profile queryset to find the difference and return object. You seem to have complicated the model structure.

Comment: i would appreciate if you could share some code as models are new for me

Comment: when i add  foreign key  to  Results_2019 it gives me such error error (1054, "Unknown column 'Results_2019.profile_id' in 'field list'")

Comment: Could you please tell us, why you have chosen to create 2 separate models for this instead of doing it one with field `year`?

Comment: this bonus question pleae share code if you your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would suggest restructuring your models so that the results link to the profile and that you have a single results model with a field for the year. I see you have the player name in your results classes, but this can be accessed via the relationship to the Player model such as `result.player.firstname`. As a side note, models are usually referred to in the singular, i.e. Profile, not Profiles.

```py
class Player(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Result(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='results')
    year = models.IntegerField() # this is where you would store 2018 or 2019    
    score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=1000)
```

I have also removed the first_score and second_score so that each result just has a single score field. You would therefore have a Result object for each score and year which should make it easier to use annotate, aggregate, and filter.

You're certainly on the right lines of using annotate to create your desired growth value but this is hampered by your model layout. Once you've restructured your models, you can get the growth like this:

```py
score1 = Avg('results__score', filter=Q(results__year=2018))
score2 = Avg('results__score', filter=Q(results__year=2019))
player_growth = Player.objects.values().annotate(growth=(score2/score1)*100)
```

Note that using 'results__score' uses the related name set in the player field and gets the score from each result linked to that player.

The above should return something like this (using dummy data):

```
{'id': 1, 'firstname': 'John', 'surname': 'Smith', 'growth': Decimal('110.0')}
```

**Edit:** If you aren't able to change the model structure then here's something else that will work, adding a method to the Player model. Note, you should change the Result relationship to a OneToOneField.

```py
def get_first_score_growth(self):
    return self.results_2019.first_score / self.results_2018.first_score * 100
```

You can call this in a template like so:

```html
{% for player in players %}
    {{ player.get_first_score_growth }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I can't change the name of models as profiles is the name of table in DB whihc i can't change the same applies to Result_2019 as there are at least results from 2010-2019

Comment: your code gives me error (1054, "Unknown column 'Results_2019.profile_id' in 'field list'")

Comment: That's because my code doesn't use Results_2019, it just has a single Result model - I would strongly recommend switching, you can do so by renaming the Profile model and creating a custom migration. I will update my answer with something specific to your setup.

Comment: i renamed Profiles, but for Result i can't cause  there are tables with Results_2019, Results_2018, Results_2017, Results_2016, Results_2015

Comment: You can merge them, here's a question on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38006144/how-to-merge-two-django-models-tables-into-one-model-table

Answer (score 0):

Your model structure seems very complicated. Why are you creating different table for each year? Just add a `year` field in Result table and this should do your work.

Model

```
class Result(models.Model):
    player=models.ForeignKeyField(Profiles)

    first_score=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)
    second_score=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)
    year=models.CharField(max_length=4)

    class Meta:
        db_table='result'
```

Now you can write your query to get desired data.

Comment: This might be better as a comment since it does not answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not you will need to do this calculation once or multiple times, I might create a new column. Creating a new column now will make this easier for future calculations. If you do not want to create a new column, you could find which people grew in each year and make a list.

If they appear in both lists, then you know they grew in both 2018 and 2019.

```
def myPageView(request):
    GrowthNames = []

    # loop through both tables
    for MyResults in [Results_2018, Results_2019]:

        # Get all objects and calculate growth
        results_list = MyResults.objects.all()
        for result in results_list:
            score1 = result.first_score
            score2 = result.second_score
            growth = (score2 - score1) / score1

            # if growth is > 20%, add it to our list
            if growth > .02:
                GrowthNames.append(results.player_name)


    # Now, we must find which items appear in our list twice (once for 2018, once for 2019)
    DoubleGrowthNames = list(set([x for x in GrowthNames if GrowthNames.count(x) == 2])

    # With our list our names, we can now get their surnames via querying
    FinalNames = []
    for name in DoubleGrowthNames:
        MyProfile = Profile.objects.filter(player_name=name)[0] 
        FinalNames.append(f'{MyProfile.player_name} {MyProfile.player_surname}')

    # Finally, let's return this to the template
    return render(request, 'page.html', {'FinalNames': FinalNames})
```

In page.html:

```
{% for name in FinalNames %}
<div>{{name}}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Results_2019 object has no attribute 'player_surname' i get this error ? how to fix it ?

Comment: @Günel edited answer, was querying from the wrong table where we do ```Profile.objects.filter(player_name=name)[0]```

Comment: hey this works but i want to make multiple calculations inside. Your code is not for multiple calculations based on multiple values that are much more that i listed. So how to make column as i understood your code is list ? right ?

Comment: @Günel What do you mean "multiple calculations"? If you need to do a different calculation, then in the section where we calculate the growth, you can replace the logic there with a different calculation. If your question is more complicated than the question you asked above, you should ask a new question.

Comment: OK I understand. Yeah, if you're doing the same calculation multiple times, it might be easier to just create a new column with the growth in each of your results tables. The solution here depends on whether you've already put data in your database. Either way, you'd start by making a new column called "growth," and then setting something up where it's automatically populated with the result of the growth calculation. Creating that is a separate question, but you might want to take a look here: ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847829/django-orm-to-sum-two-columns-to-fill-a-third-one```

Comment: @Günel -- I think you should be able to convert the code in the original answer and add more logic.

Comment: @Günel Yes for example: if you also wanted to check whether 2nd score was over 80, you could replace ```if (growth > .02)``` with ```if (growth > .02) and (score2 > 80):```

Comment: @Günel The first thing you need to do is set it up so that the first name and last name are not concatenated in the view. So instead do:         ```FinalNames.append([MyProfile.player_name, MyProfile.player_surname])```. Then in your template you can do ```{% for name in FinalNames %}{% for fn, ln in FinalNames %}<div>{{fn}}</div><div>{{ln}}</div>{% endfor %}{% endfor %}```

Comment: hey while applying you code it seems to have limitations. i wanted to add table to list whereas columns differ but still have the same player_name Model Paramenters ( columns : weight, height ) that i wanted to divided by first_score . So when i tried to add model Paramenters to results_list it gives me and error : 'Results_2019' object has no attribute 'weight'.  Why is this ? how to fix it as it makes code unreplicable .

Comment: @Günel I believe your question is unrelated to this initial question, and should be a new question.

Comment: i asked you as i am talking about your answer to my question that has limitations.